# Installing object_detection_server on Fuerte for TOD (Textured Object Detector)

Tags: ros, object-detection, ecto

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I'm trying to test **PR2 Interactive Object Detection**. When you load it up in Rviz, there is a "Detect" button which calls the **recognition_translator** node (an optional install), but this node requires the **object_recognition_server** package.

With Fuerte, I can install the following packages:

> ros-fuerte-object-recognition-capture 
> ros-fuerte-object-recognition-core 
> ros-fuerte-object-recognition-linemod  
> ros-fuerte-object-recognition-msgs 
> ros-fuerte-object-recognition-reconstruction 
> ros-fuerte-object-recognition-ros 
> ros-fuerte-object-recognition-tod      
> ros-fuerte-object-recognition-transparent-objects

But I had to get the server package from here:

> https://github.com/wg-perception/ros-object_recognition

which also has the -core and -msgs packages, so it's probably not compatible.

I'm trying to load the server with this launch file:

```
<launch>
  <arg name="config_file" default="config_detection.table" />
  <node pkg="object_recognition_server" ns="/object_recognition" name="object_recognition_server" output="screen" type="server.py" args="-c $(find object_recognition_server)/conf/$(arg config_file)">
  </node>
</launch>
```

and this config file:

```
source1:
  type: ros_kinect
  rgb_frame_id: '/camera_rgb_optical_frame'

sink1:
  type: table_publisher
  package: 'tabletop'

pipeline1:
  method: 'tabletop_table'
  package: 'tabletop'
  submethod: ''
  sources: [source1]
  sinks: [sink1]
  parameters: {}
```

which produces this error:

```
rospy args stripped ['-c', '/home/user/ros_workspace/object_recognition/object_recognition_server/conf/config_detection.table']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/ros_workspace/object_recognition/object_recognition_server/server.py", line 88, in <module>
    server = RecognitionServer(args)
  File "/home/user/ros_workspace/object_recognition/object_recognition_server/server.py", line 15, in __init__
    self.plasm = create_detection_plasm()
TypeError: create_detection_plasm() takes exactly 4 arguments (0 given)
[ INFO] [1358271985.462667749]: waitForService: Service [/tabletop_object_recognition] has not been advertised, waiting...
[object_recognition/object_recognition_server-3] process has died [pid 24531, exit code 1, cmd /home/user/ros_workspace/object_recognition/object_recognition_server/server.py -c /home/user/ros_workspace/object_recognition/object_recognition_server/conf/config_detection.table __name:=object_recognition_server __log:=/home/user/ros_.ros/log/e17fdb50-5f39-11e2-9490-1078d2868e5d/object_recognition-object_recognition_server-3.log].
log file: /home/user/ros_.ros/log/e17fdb50-5f39-11e2-9490-1078d2868e5d/object_recognition-object_recognition_server-3*.log
```

Please what am I missing here?

cheers, 
David.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52331/installing-object_detection_server-on-fuerte-for-tod-(textured-object-detector)/) by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1103 on 2013-01-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Anything Electric has been deleted: it was a big hack anyway.

Fuerte and Groovy have almost the same code so it works on both. What you are looking for is the actionlib server:

rosrun object_recognition_ros server.py -c /opt/ros/groovy/share/object_recognition_tabletop/conf/config_detection.tabletop_table

(I just released a tabletop package). Expect doc updates on that in the next few days.

We have indeed not synced our APIs in a while with the interactive_manipulation folks. We are working on that. Any help is welcome :)

---

Originally posted by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) with karma: 1111 on 2013-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) on 2013-01-23**:
Great, thanks @vincent-rabaud What needs to be done to sync those 2 systems?